# Exact probability in the context of hoeffding bounds

Tags: probability-theory

Hi I am trying to solve an exercise that is part of a context of comparing Hoeffding's bound to Markov and Chebyshev bounds w.r.t coin tossing where we look at 1.000.000 empirical trials of 20 each with a bias of 1/2.
After having made some plots and comparisons of the bounds they ask us to:

$\text { For } \alpha=1 \text { and } \alpha=0.95 \text { calculate the exact probability } \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{20} \sum_{i=1}^{20} X_{i} \geq \alpha\right)$

I am unsure of how to understand this exact probability, when they also look at a bound of alpha.
Am I to just use the Bernouille trials and determine the probability of the number of stipulated occurrences k of the event that the coin turns out to be head? Such that  by

$P_{(k \text { out of } N)}=\frac{N !}{k !(N-k) !}\left(p^{k}\right)\left(q^{N-k}\right)$

It is the case that $\alpha = 1$ when we have 20 out 20 heads of the coin toss. This gives us

$P_{(20 \text { out of } 20)}=\frac{20 !}{20 !*0!}\left(0.5^{20}\right)\left(0.5^{0}\right)$

for $\alpha = 1$ and likewise by 'translating' $\alpha = 0.95 \to k = 19$ for the other value.

**EDIT**

I think what I am looking for is a confirmation of disconfirmation of whether or not I am heading in the right direction.
As I have stated I already have an idea about how to approach the problem. I am however unsure of the meaning of the "exact" probability but suspect that it is different from the 'empirically sampled' probability you would get if you just plot it. But when you plot it you are still using the Bernioulli trials however with different values of $\alpha$ and that would mean the exact and the empirical probability would be similar as I see it.

The code for empirically sampling would look something like the following:

```
def Bernoulli(trials, bias, sample_size):  
  return np.random.binomial(trials, bias, sample_size)
```

where I am here using the numpy library with the random binomial distribution: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html

Comment: You are correct, the exact probability for $\alpha=0.95$ will be $P$(20 out of 20) $+P$(19 out of 20). The 'empirically sampled probability' is in other words an estimate of the probability of an event $A$, estimated by actually simulating the data and counting how many times $A$ occurs out of all trials. This estimate may differ for each simulation but should generally be close to the exact probability (with high probability...)

Comment: Wait $\alpha = 0.95$ will have  probability $P(19 \text{ out of } 20)$ not $P(20 \text{ out of } 20) + P(19 \text{ out of } 20)$. Probabiliyt $P(20 \text{ out of } 20)$ is solely for $\alpha = 1$ right

Comment: Because the probability to be calculated says "ratio $\geq 0.95$", you need to consider both cases (20 heads out of 20, ratio = 1.0) AND (19 heads out of 20, ratio = 0.95) and add their probabilities.

Comment: But would that then imply that you would have $P(20 \text{ out of }20) +P(19 \text{ out of }20) ... + P(1 \text{ out of }20)$ for $\alpha = 0.05 $? I thought the formula I stated in my question actually took this into account.

Comment: That is correct. $P(\text{ratio} \geq 0.05) = P(\text{number of heads} \geq 1) = P(\text{number of heads} = 1 \text{ or } 2 \text{ or } 3 \text{ or} \cdots \text{ or } 20)$, so you need to add all the probabilities $P(\text{exactly }k \text{ out of } 20)$ for $k=1$ to $20$. Your formula is for the single probability $P(\text{exactly }k \text{ out of } 20)$.

Comment: Of course, for $\alpha=0.05$ one would instead simply compute $1-P(0 \text{ out of } 20) = 1-0.5^{20}$.

Comment: Ah, now I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reasoning is correct.
Furthermore $P($ ratio $\geq 0.05)=P($ number of heads $\geq 1)=P($ number of heads $=1$ or 2 or 3 or $\cdots$ or 20$)$, so you need to add all the probabilities $P$ (exactly $k$ out of 20 ) for $k=1$ to 20 . Your formula is for the single probability $P$ (exactly $k$ out of 20$)$.